# Owned by a family F of subsets of a metric space closed.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This is the problem:
For a family F of subsets of closed non-empty metric space consider the following two properties.

a) Every point in space admits a neighborhood which intersects at most one infinite number of members of F.

b) The union of the members of any subfamily of F is a closed set.

it is true that a) implies b)? it is true that b) implies a)?

I know that b) is true for a finite family of closed sets and it is not true for infinite families. I think that a) implies b), but I could not prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have a typo in (a): it should say that each point has a neighborhood that intersects at most **finitely** many members of the family. A collection with that property is said to be *locally finite*; a collection with property (b) is said to be *closure-preserving*. It’s true that every locally finite family is closure-preserving, not just in metric spaces but in general topological spaces.

Let $X$ be a space, and let $\mathscr{F}$ be a family of closed sets in $X$. Suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is locally finite, and for each $x\in X$ let $U_x$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ that intersects only finitely many members of $\mathscr{F}$. Let $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$, and let $H=\bigcup\mathscr{C}$; we want to show that $H$ is closed in $X$. I’ll do this by showing that $X\setminus H$ is open. Let $x\in X\setminus H$; I want to find an open neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ such that $V_x\cap H=\varnothing$. Let $\mathscr{C}(x)=\{C\in\mathscr{C}:U_x\cap C\ne\varnothing\}$; by hypothesis $\mathscr{C}(x)$ is finite, so $\bigcup_{\mathscr{C}(x)}$ is closed. (Note that this makes sense even if $\mathscr{C}(x)=\varnothing$.) Let $V_x=U_x\setminus\bigcup\mathscr{C}(x)$; then $V_x$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, and $V_x\cap H=\varnothing$. Thus, $X\setminus H$ is open, and $H$ is closed. This shows that (a) implies (b).

It is not true, however, that every closure-preserving family is locally finite, even in metric spaces: in $[0,1]$ let $F_n=\left[0,\frac1n\right]$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and let $\mathscr{F}=\{F_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$.

Comment: perfect!!! thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Giacomo: You’re very welcome.

Comment: When you write "[0,1 = let" you want to said [0,1] let.

Comment: @Giacomo: Thanks! (Lazy finger.)